# Why is docker not connecting to the database?

Tags: docker

I have 2 files: docker-compose.yml, .env

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  main:
    container_name: main
    build:
      context: /home/rumeone/chat/ChatDiploma/server/chat-backend
    env_file:
      - /home/rumeone/chat/ChatDiploma/server/chat-backend/.env
    volumes:
      - /home/rumeone/chat/ChatDiploma/server/chat-backend/:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229
    command: npm run start
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: always

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:12
    env_file:
      - /home/rumeone/chat/ChatDiploma/server/chat-backend/.env
    environment:
      - PG_DATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

and such an env file

```
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_DATABASE=chat
SECRET_KEY=qwerty
```

Why does such an error appear?

```
[Nest] 29 - 06/19/2023, 4:24:02 PM ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (3)...
main | Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN postgres
main | at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
```

tried to change DB_HOST=localhost, still doesn't work, what's wrong? Is it docker-compose?

Comment: First, try to interact with postgres container by doing `docker exec -it postgres /bin/bash` (or /bin/sh). Once you are in, try doing `psql -d chat -U postgres` and see if you can log in. If you can't, you might want to figure out what's going on with that container first. If you can connect, exit postgres container and interactively access `main`. From there, you can try to do `telnet postgres 5432`. If you can connect to postgres container, great. If not, there's a connectivity issue between the 2 containers.

Comment: `Container 731c0bd998e3b1d5a7204d5a537875315a2a7c56943dfe297ebdb7e89c972c21 is restarting, wait until the container is running`. such a message is displayed, even after waiting anyway

Comment: Make a copy of your docker-compose.yml somewhere. Then, remove everything from your docker-compose.yml and just have postgres 12 like https://herewecode.io/blog/create-a-postgresql-database-using-docker-compose/ blog shows. Then, do docker compose up and make sure your container is running. You can use docker exec to log in and use psql to confirm that PostgreSQL is running and you can log into it. Once that is done, add `main` container to docker-compose.yml and try again. Build your docker-compose file step by step - first postgres, then main

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/creating-and-filling-a-postgres-db-with-docker-compose-e1607f6f882f blog also gives a great overview of how you can set up your postgres container along with, say, a new database, new user, etc.